# How to get rid of multiple X gates show up as I run the code over and over in qiskit jupyter notebook?

Tags: qiskit

I'm practising some code in Qiskit. However, I can't undo or get rid of previously applied gates.

If you take a look at the two screenshots I'm including. The more I run my code, even though I won't repeat the code, the more X gates show up.

How can I just have one even though I run the code multiple times?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just add the circuit definition (`circuit = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)`) to same Jupyter code cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not related to Qiskit, but it's actually due to how jupyter notebooks work. In the cells you are showing, the `circuit` object gets updated at each execution by adding the $X$ gate to the first qubit.
To do what you want, these two are the best options:

1. move the circuit definition in the same cell

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)
circuit.x(0)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

2. clear the circuit in the same cell

```
circuit.clear()
circuit.x(0)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you!