# Problem with qiskit environment in VSCode

Tags: qiskit

So, every time I rerun the same circuit, it keeps adding more gates instead printing the same thing over. Like if I need to add something new to the existing circuit, it will add the just of the gates again as well.

What to do with this? This doesn't when I am using the Jupyter notebook in the chrome. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29619/how-to-get-rid-of-multiple-x-gates-show-up-as-i-run-the-code-over-and-over-in-qi/29620#29620)

Comment: @MartinVesely yes it does. Thanx!